# Flutter: Lost connection to device (Windows)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

my flutter app crashes sometimes.
I am using AndroidStudio for debugging and when I run or debug it in AndroidStudio I only get in console `Lost connection to device.`
I have also implemented sentry.io, but this does not send the error to sentry.
Can you tell me, how I can get a log of what causes the crash?